# Can you upload an entire working set to GitHub from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github, working-set

I'm studying computer science and I recently grouped all my projects by course to working sets.
Is there a way to upload a working set as a single project to GitHub?
It seems as if the working set folder doesn't really exist, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

for example, I have 12 projects named lab1-lab12, and I added them all to the working set called "Intro to computer science". can this working set be uploaded to GitHub?
Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK you can't *initialize* a repository from a Working Set (which, as you suspect, are not actual folders). Your projects need to be located in the same Git repository and I don't think EGit handles the trouble of moving existing projects in a single place. However, once all the projects are in a Git repo you can manage them all from the Working Sets (see [bug 311299](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=311299))

Comment: To move multiple projects into a single repository: select the projects, right-click and choose _Team > Share Project..._ @EmmanuelChebbi